# What do you gain by training Kerbals?

Tags: kerbal-space-program

Now that Kerbals can learn and develop skills I wonder what is increasing the skill level? Is it the number of flights? distance traveled? Time in space? biomes visited?

Also, what does leveling my Kerbals do? Do they get better at certain tasks? If so, what is unlocked at each level?

Comment: You are asking two questions: 1. how to train them and 2. what benefit you get from training them. It would be better to split this into two separate questions so they can be answered separately.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Kerbal Experience and Skills
>
> Your favorite Kerbals have gained specific skillsets when they’re hired: your pilots, scientists and engineers will each gain abilities specific to their specialization as they earn experience by going on missions in outer space. Pilots will learn how a ship is controlled and will be able to take over control of your spacecraft’s orientation or provide stability control during flight; scientists give you an edge when it comes to collecting scientific data as their analytical skills give bonuses to science collection; and an experienced engineer can repair specific parts of your craft which may save your mission.

Taken from http://forum.kerbalspaceprogram.com/threads/103034

Comment: While providing an excerpt from an external source is good, it's also usually a good idea to provide some original content.  Even if it's just a summary of what's at the link.

Comment: True, I just felt it was a pretty good summary I could'nt improve it :/

Comment: The information you are providing is very superficial. The question asked *which circumstances exactly* cause a Kerbal to gain experience and *which bonuses exactly* they get on *each* level. Please try to provide a more in-depth answer which goes beyond the obvious and explains the exact game mechanics which are involved. What I would expect from a great answer to this question would be a list for each profession what they gain on each level, a list of activities and how many exp points they provide and a list of how many exp points are required to reach each level.

Comment: that info isn't released yet :( posted link to forum so should such details come available they can be found there on that exact topic :)